# New layout for Stack Overflow is not helpful for me

Tags: feature-request

I opened SO this morning and thought I have pressed the wrong button or had a misconfigured browser... but it seems that is a wanted design change.

What I miss:

- the yellow background under questions which I have in my tag list is very helpful but gone now!
- the "watched" label is not in the meaning of "I am watching" this question... My expectation is, that we see that highlighted field if *we* watch the question. But watching means *we* have selected this exact question to watch it!
- The "votes" helps *me* to find the important questions and also the trash. We all know that it is important these days to fast close all the unrelated off-topic, bad style and simply useless questions. But now? Only a very small number in the same size as the number of views and answers. Sorry, I want the old vote style back!
- The page layout seems to be wasting 50% of my screen simply blank. Why?
- The number views did not help me at all in the overview page. That is only helpful for statistical purposes. That other users are not interested in a questions says simply nothing about my current interest if *I* go on the page. Number of views help *me* for *my* questions. If I see fewer responses and no helpful answers on *my* questions, the number of views give me feedback that I may have given a bad headline. But the number of views is not needed on the top page at all.

Can we please have the "old style", maybe as a user configurable option? Content and layout are different things. So it seems in days of style sheets more or less easy to give the user the freedom to take the design decision simply by providing some sheets.

Comment: @Klaus All of this has been covered multiple times on MSE: [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/289905). I know that [you’re not registered there](/q/415540/4642212#comment891367_415540), but Meta Stack Exchange is where these major changes are announced and discussed, so why not start today?

Comment: I agree with all except that the number of views is actually useful. I use it all the time

Comment: @Gimby The more, the merrier? I would expect the existing posts result in a rollback faster than you can say "does someone have a userscript". But for some strange reason that didn't happen.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You might want to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375477/can-i-ask-for-a-recent-feature-change-to-be-reverted-in-whole-and-what-are-the Theres a severe disconnect here.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. FYI, there's a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacy-questions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design) and [userstyles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375511/158281) (CSS only) in the announcement responses